# Azure http and blog trigger functions can't process any file larger than 4 mb on consumption plan

Tags: azure-functions

Azure http and blog trigger functions can't process any file larger than 4 mb on consumption plan, any reason why and how to overcome this problem ?

Comment: According to this the max request size for HTTP trigger is 100 MB? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#limits

Comment: And for blob trigger I think you can use the Blob Storage SDK types instead of byte[] or string to read them in blocks; you don't need to read the whole file at once if your scenario allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Scale out your functions manually by defining multiple function apps instead of a single function app. In theory this should result in a lot better scaling since you now have many independent apps processing messages in parallel. As you would expect this made for a good performance improvement.

For Complete information check Scaling Queue Triggered Azure Functions and Also check Scaling Azure Functions.

[check here](https://madeofstrings.com/2019/01/09/scaling-azure-functions-to-make-500000-requests-to-weather-com-in-under-3-minutes/)